# Display data on the basis of development and production environment in Ionic 3

Tags: android, angular, ionic3

I am trying to display a conditional ion-select on my page which will be visible only when apk is develop for development purpose. I don't want to show that ion-select in my apk which is develop for production purpose. This select will change the overall Url for our Api's. I have tried different solutions which are not working. Some of them are as follow:

http://roblouie.com/article/296/ionic-2-environment-variables-the-best-way/
https://medium.com/@hin556/managing-environment-variables-in-ionic-2-43506f49acfb
https://masimplo.com/using-environment-config-in-ionic2/index.html
https://artyomsokolov.com/tag/typescript/

I have tried all of the above solutions and many more but they are returning same data for production as returning for development. How can i achieve my ultimate goal. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add in a configuration file of your own, let's say `config.ts`, the value for your environment:

```
export const CONFIG: any = {
  prodEnv: false,
  apiUrl: null,
  devApiUrl: 'http://localhost/app_dev.php/api/',
  prodApiUrl: 'https://api.test.com/api/'
};
```

Somewhere in your `AppComponent` in the constructor, you should define the default value for your `CONFIG.apiUrl`.

In your page where you want the select to be displayed, in the ts file add the following:

```
get isProd() {
  return CONFIG.prodEnv;
}   
setProd(event) {
  CONFIG.prodEnv = event;
  CONFIG.apiUrl = event ? CONFIG.prodApiUrl : CONFIG.devApiUrl;
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<ion-select *ngIf="!isProd" name="environment" (ionChange)="setProd($event)">
   <ion-option [value]="true">Production</ion-option>
   <ion-option [value]="false" [selected]="!isProd">Development</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i want to show ion-select depending upon environment variables. Let suppose if environment variable is "development" then i want to show that ion-select and if environment variable is "production" then i don't want to show the ion-select

Comment: This is exactly what it is doing, the only thing is that it is not using ionic environment variables, but you set your own through `prodEnv: true` which means that default environment is production and if you set it to `false`, it's development environment. You can use them for any inside checks. If this doesn't help you, hopefully somebody will come up with a more appropriate answer for you.